# MSGestureHold is ignored by WebBrowser Control for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-11, windows-phone-8.1

I am updating my browser app to support Windows Phone 8.1 and I noticed the `MSGestureHold`event is not raised.

To reproduce this error,

1. Download the [MS Mini-browser Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Mini-browser-Sample-b5587d2b).
2. Upgrade the project to WP8.1 project in Visual Studio 2013 and add `IsScriptEnabled="True"`.
3. Run the project on WP8.1 emulator or device
4. Navigate to this [touch and mouse example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2013/02/20/handling-touch-in-your-html5-apps-thanks-to-the-pointer-events-of-ie10-and-windows-8.aspx).
5. Scroll down to the `Sample 1: handling the hold gesture` section and [click the IE11 users test](http://david.blob.core.windows.net/html5/PECR/touchsample6.html).

Notice that `MSGestureHold` is not working.

However the project is working when tested in

1. Default Windows Phone Internet Explorer app for WP8 and WP8.1
2. WebBrowser control in WP8 app.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the WebBrowser control's bug.

I test several gesture events with WebBrowser control for WP8.1, such as **pointerdown**,**MSGestureHold**,**MSGestureChange**,and **MSGestureTap**.
Finally, **pointerdown**, **MSGestureChange** and **MSGestureTap** can be triggered normally,except **MSGestureHold**.
So I guess this is a **bug**.

Comment: What exactly did you do? I am having trouble receiving GestureChange event in WP8.1.  Also, there is no WebBrowser control for WP8.1

Comment: WP8.1 also has WebBrowser control, maybe you should import some library.
If you want to catch gesture hold event, you can catch **onmousedown** and **onmouseup** event instead of catching **MSGestureHold** event.

Comment: No, afaik the webbrowser control was turned into webview control with a slightly different functionality

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine in webview for WPhone 8.1 apps :

```
var init = function(){
    var myState = // context
    var target = // DOM variable target
    var msg = new MSGesture();

    msg.target = target;

    target.addEventListener("MSGestureHold", function (evt) { buttonTactileListener.apply(myState, [evt, msg]); }, false);
    target.addEventListener("pointerdown", function (evt) { buttonTactileListener.apply(myState, [evt, msg]); }, false);
    target.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd", function (evt) { buttonTactileListener.apply(myState, [evt, msg]); }, false);
}
var buttonTactileListener = function (evt, msgesture) {
    var myState = this;
    if (evt.type == "pointerdown") {
        msgesture.addPointer(evt.pointerId);
        return;
    }
    if (evt.type == "MSGestureHold") {
        ///do something
        return;
    }

    if (evt.type == "MSGestureEnd") {
        // renew instance of handler
        msgesture = new MSGesture();
        msgesture.target = evt.target;
        return;
    }
}
```