# windows phone 8.1 javascript tap and hold feature

Tags: winjs, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows phone 8.1, I want to show context menu (popup) for an item in listview (say for deleting it) upon tap-and-hold or long press. Is there a way to do this in javascript (winjs)?

I found no examples of this anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to take a look at the [MSGestureHold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465866.aspx) event. You just need to add an event handler for that event.

Take a look at the [MSGestureEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441180.aspx) object for more events you might need

Answer (score 0):

In my test, the MSGestureHold is not fired in Windows Phone 8.1 for some reason. It's possible that this is a bug. [MSGestureHold is ignored by WebBrowser Control for Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209243/msgesturehold-is-ignored-by-webbrowser-control-for-windows-phone-8-1)

One possible workaround is to switch to XAML framework and use the WebView control but in my case it's not possible as I depend heavily on Silverlight controls.