# MSGestureHold event not triggered in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8

My app uses Silverlight 8.0 SDK, the `MSGestureHold` event works on Windows 8, but if the same is tested on 8.1 the event is not triggered.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209243/msgesturehold-is-ignored-by-webbrowser-control-for-windows-phone-8-1

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine in webview for WPhone 8.1 apps :

```
var init = function(){
    var myState = // context
    var target = // DOM variable target
    var msg = new MSGesture();

    msg.target = target;

    target.addEventListener("MSGestureHold", function (evt) { buttonTactileListener.apply(myState, [evt, msg]); }, false);
    target.addEventListener("pointerdown", function (evt) { buttonTactileListener.apply(myState, [evt, msg]); }, false);
    target.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd", function (evt) { buttonTactileListener.apply(myState, [evt, msg]); }, false);
}
var buttonTactileListener = function (evt, msgesture) {
    var myState = this;
    if (evt.type == "pointerdown") {
        msgesture.addPointer(evt.pointerId);
        return;
    }
    if (evt.type == "MSGestureHold") {
        ///do something
        return;
    }

    if (evt.type == "MSGestureEnd") {
        // renew instance of handler
        msgesture = new MSGesture();
        msgesture.target = evt.target;
        return;
    }
}
```